# How to install poppler from source with all its dependencies

Tags: cmake

I have a shared host, therefore I don't have access to `apt` to install new packages. I want to install `poppler` on it. So I went to https://poppler.freedesktop.org/ and downloaded the source archive file. I managed to compile it and installed the binary files on a folder. Everything seems OK, but the problem is the dependent libraries are not installed. Is it possible to have the dependencies alongside the compiled files?

Answer (score 1):

OK. I found out I can use [Xpdf command line tools](http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html) instead of Poppler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pip for install distribution version
https://cbrunet.net/python-poppler/installation.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).